# Linux run bash script as root but no permission to chmod inside script

Tags: linux, bash

I have a bash script that I run like:

```
sudo ./AddNewUser.sh user7 qwerty
```

Inside the script there is (amongst many other lines)

```
chown $1 $homeBaseDir/$1/upload
```

I just keep getting back an error:
chown: changing ownership of '/media/pi/CORSAIR/user7/upload': Operation not permitted

Why isn't it permitted if the script is running as root? The directory mentioned is there and the user exists.

Comment: try insert `sudo` before `chown` in the script.

Comment: Might I then have the problem of that needing the password to be re-entered? I'll try it.

Comment: I wonder if this some sticky bit permissions devilry. Was are the permissions `ls -l` on the script?

Comment: Adding sudo in front of chown inside script still had permission denied. Here is the output of ls -l for the script: -rwxr--r-- 1 pi pi  1094 Jun 11 15:23 AddNewUser.sh

Comment: `/media/pi/CORSAIR/user7/upload` is not `AddNewUser.sh`. Did you call the `chown` inside a function?

Comment: @PaulHodges I called chown inside the script (not a function). TenG asked me for the permissions on the script inself I thought, not the upload directory.

Comment: drwxr-x---+ 3 root root 4096 Jun 10 12:25 pi    The pi directory does have a +, if that means a sticky bit

Comment: @Paul, to troubleshoot this, can you successfully run chown on that file path manually? This is possibly the expected behavior when trying to run commands that need root permissions from within a scrip.  If you are able to run `sudo chown user7 //media/pi/CORSAIR/user7/upload/` manually, then the scrip is behaving normally but first we need to  confirm if you are able to run it manually.

Comment: correction: `sudo chown user7 /media/pi/CORSAIR/user7/upload/`

Comment: Running the command manually has the same problem so its not to do with the script specifically. I think its because the file system is vfat, i'll remount the drive.

Comment: Ah, ok! Yeah, if it's a vfat, then Linux permissions will not be supported. Remounting a drive with desirable umask bits should stir you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

**/media/pi/CORSAIR/user7/upload** seems like a mounted directory

Use the 'mount' command in order to see if you've mounted this directory with Read-Write permissions.

Alternatively you can use 'lsattr' to check if there are any file-system attributes that deny you permissions for some reason.

Comment: Thanks, this is the output from mount :  /dev/sda1 on /media/pi/CORSAIR type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,showexec,utf8,flush,errors=remount-ro,uhelper=udisks2)

Comment: @Paul it may be because it's a vfat mount and doesn't save the permissions in the filesystem (they'd just come from the mount options no matter what you set on the files/directories)

Comment: Not entirely sure if that's the reason for this "permission denied", but I think FAT filesystems do not follow the Unix permissions model. It's all about the way you mount it and the options you pass. Do you think this "chown" operation from your script is actually needed?

Comment: Thanks, I guess it is because its vfat, i'll look into changing it. I do need to chown really because i want to set some permissions on a directory that are unique to a particular user.

Answer (score 0):

a}  Check the permissions of everything involved.

If you're trying to do something on a mounted drive, mount and its' parameters are definitely the first thing I would check, but have a good look around with "ls -l" with the relevant files and note the security settings.

b}  I'm actually on the less paranoid side of things where security is concerned, but the idea of automating things as root still *really* makes me uncomfortable.

In my experience, the reason to avoid using root isn't because I'm worried about getting broken into remotely by some bored 14 year old from Vladivostok.  It's because I know how easy it is to write "rm -rf /usr" when I'm tired or distracted, because I've already done it.

The ideal way to use sudo, isn't just to do everything as root; but instead to create different users (an "adduser" account in this case) with the specific permissions you need for a given task, and then use sudo to switch to *them.*

UNIX was mocked by pre-iOS Apple users for years about how the security model was a blunt instrument.  With sudo, however, we can create a more delicate and subtle setup than any other operating system you can think of; it's just that you have to do it yourself, and it takes work.  It doesn't come out of the box.